# How do I insert an emoji in a Java string?

Tags: java, string, emoji

I am trying to make a program which prints out emoji.  However, it won't let me insert an emoji in the SDK, and the `\u` doesn't allow for enough characters to use an emoji.  Is there any simple way to do this?

All of the online solutions seem to refer to a `StringBuffer`.  Is there any way to do this without a `StringBuffer`?  If not, how would I use this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the OP asks for a solution without StringBuffer.

Comment: like this    ____       : )

Comment: What emoji? If you mean e.g.  ['GRINNING FACE' (U+1F600)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm), then write `""` if your source code is UTF-8, or `"\uD83D\uDE00"` if not.

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for sending server-side notifications using SNS then following works

```
String context = "You can eat water too! ";
        context += new String(Character.toChars(0x1F349));
```

[various emoji unicodes](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Answer (score 6):

It can be done, without using `StringBuilder`, with [Unicode surrogate pair](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2274038&seqNum=10):

> Surrogate characters are typically referred to as *surrogate pairs*.
>   They are the combination of two characters, containing a single code
>   point. To make the detection of surrogate pairs easy, the Unicode
>   standard has reserved the range from U+D800 to U+DFFF for the use of
>   UTF-16. No characters are assigned to code point values in this range.
>   When programs see a bit sequence that falls in this range, they
>   immediately—zip! zip!—know that they have encountered a surrogate
>   pair.
>
> This reserved range is composed of two parts:
>
> - **High surrogates** — U+D800 to U+DBFF (total of 1,024 code points)
> - **Low surrogates** — U+DC00 to U+DFFF (total of 1,024 code points)

The following would print extraterrestrial alien emoji ():

```
int[] surrogates = {0xD83D, 0xDC7D};
String alienEmojiString = new String(surrogates, 0, surrogates.length);
System.out.println(alienEmojiString);
System.out.println("\uD83D\uDC7D");   // alternative way
```

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if it included a quick explanation of what UTF-16 is, why Java Strings require it, and why  is expressed as `\uD83D\uDC7D`.

Comment: Here's a online encoder/decoder that will generate the surrogate pairs when given an emoji and vice-versa: http://russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm